# Calling Linux Password Dialog by Using Python-GTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, gtk, gtk3

I have Python code that uses GTK GUI. Clicking a button will call password dialog on linux before some code execution. How could I call this dialog?

Process name of the dialog looks as: `python call polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` on the task manager (I have tried to update Catfish database and controlled the password dialog name on the task manager).

Note: I am a new linux user.

System details: GTK3, Debian-like Linux.